# how to find the order of an element in a quotient group

Tags: group-theory

Consider the quotient group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of the additive group of rational numbers. Then how to find the order of the element $2/3 + \mathbb{Z} $ in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supplementing Makoto's answer, we can generalize: the order of an element $p/q \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the least integer $n$ such that $(p/q)n$ is an integer. If the fraction is written in reduced form, this is the same as the denominator.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a =  2/3 + \mathbb{Z}$.
Since $3a = 0$ and $a \neq 0$, the order of $a$ is $3$.

Comment: @ram: Note that in Makoto's nice answer(+1); $3a=0=0_{\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z}=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a coset $a + \mathbb Z$ and $a$ has given by  is the smallest positive integer $b$ such that $b(a+\mathbb Z)= \mathbb Z$.